# Get country name in specific language, other than the system wide selected language

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I need to solve the following problem. It seems simple but I'm stuck.

I'm writing a converter which takes as input the  Geographic Region Code of a country and should return the name of the country in the display language of the application.

**Example** (target functionality)

Application language: "FR"

Input: "US"

Output: "États Unis"

To this end I use the following code.

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string countryCode = (string)value;                       
        var country = new Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion(countryCode);
        return country.DisplayName;

    }
```

The problem with this is that it returns the country in the system wide selected language. For example.

**Example 2**

System Language: "en-US"

Application Language (set via [PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh972398?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) : "FR"

Input: "US"

Output: United States

I suspect that what happens is the `Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion` class gets its culture data from the System wide settings and not from the Application culture settings .

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Is there a way to set a different culture for the thread the converter will run in?

Comment: Might be a bug, doesn't seem to take the system settings either as I changed my system default language to both French and Dutch to test.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for taking the time to check this. Can you tell me what you tried and what results you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeographicRegion.DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.geographicregion.displayname) can get a localized string that is suitable for display to the user for identifying the region. However this function requires corresponding language pack to be installed.

For example, to display the region in French, we need to install **Français language pack** by opening **Settings → Time & Language → Region & language → Add a language**.
[image]

Note that we don't need to set French as the default language, so the system language is still English.

After French language pack is installed, your code should be able to return the localized region name in French. For example, when you input "US", the output should be "États-Unis".

Comment: Jay Zuo Thanks for answering my question. Indeed after I installed the language pack it works. However, I am creating an app that offers the user the option to choose a display language that may not be installed in the system. 
Is there a way to get a localized name for a country depending on its Geographic Region Code using the Windows.Globalization APIs without knowing that the language pack is installed?

Comment: @Corcus We can't get a localized name without installing corresponding language pack while using Windows.Globalization APIs. The language pack is like the .resw resources files we use to support localization. Without it, the API can not retrieve corresponding localized name.

Comment: @Corcus I'm not sure how many region codes you want to support. If not many, you can put them into resources files and retrieve in code like [Put UI strings into resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources). Otherwise, you can use some online services like [GetLanguageNames Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512414.aspx) in [Microsoft Translator API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to support a large number of countries (over 100). I will see what I can do. Thanks for answering my question :)